# AsyncTask source code questions

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I was reading [AsyncTask.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) and there are few places that I can't understand.

1. What does this code actually do? Judging by the comment it should create the handler, but I can't get how it can do this. The method `getLooper()` in the `Handler` class just returns the handler, so there is no way I can see it can initialize a new handler.

   ```
   /** @hide Used to force static handler to be created. */
   public static void init() {
       sHandler.getLooper();
   }
   ```
2. Why putting `postResultIfNotInvoked()` in the overriden `done()` method? How can it be not invoked? If I understand this right, first the `call()` method of `mWorker` will be called and then `mTaskInvoked` is guaranteed to be true.

   ```
   mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
       public Result call() throws Exception {
           mTaskInvoked.set(true);
           //...
           return postResult(doInBackground(mParams));
       }
   };

   mFuture = new FutureTask<Result>(mWorker) {
       @Override
       protected void done() {
           try {
               postResultIfNotInvoked(get());
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               android.util.Log.w(LOG_TAG, e);
           } catch (ExecutionException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException("An error occured while executing doInBackground()",
                       e.getCause());
           } catch (CancellationException e) {
               postResultIfNotInvoked(null);
           }
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: I would think getLooper also inits something. I would think postIfNotInvoked is just a name you have to look inside it if you want to know what it does.

Comment: I looked in the code of `postResultIfNotInvoked` and it does pretty uch what it says. It checks if mTaskInvoked is false and if it is it launches the postResult. But I can't see a way it can be false at that time. 
You might want to see that code in the link I have in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `init()` isn't really used in regular code.

   It can be used in platform test code - calling it first makes the class loader initialize the static members on the current thread. It's useful to making sure the `Handler` is created on the main UI thread while tests run on a background thread for example.

   Because of `@hide`, it's not usable in code written with SDK's stub version of `android.jar`.
2. This is there to [fix a bug to make sure `onCancelled()` is called if `cancel()` is called early](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5ba812b9e9c886425a5736c2ae6fbe0fc94afd8b%5E%21/#F0).